# Scoping issue with dcast and knitr

Tags: r, data.table, knitr

I've created a simple R file called `test.R`:

```
library(knitr)

file <- "test.Rmd"

k <- function(input, output){
  knit(input, output)
}

k(file, "badtest.md")

knit(file, "goodtest.md")

k(file, "badtest2.md")
```

Accompanying it is a small Rmd file called `test.Rmd`:

````
```{r define, echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE} 
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(data.table))
xsum <- function(x){
  sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```
```{r, echo = FALSE}
mt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
f <- function(d){
  dcast(d,  drat ~ cyl, fun.aggregate = list(xsum), value.var = "carb") 
}

f(mt)[1:5]

```
````

The goal is to run the `xsum` function on the data. In the first case where the `knit` call is inside a function (`badtest.md`), it fails with `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "xsum"`.

The second case (`goodtest.md`) is outside of a function and it succeeds.

The third case (`badtest2.md`) is the same as the first, but it also succeeds now that the second case has run.

**Why does this scoping issue occur and how can I resolve it so that I can use `xsum` or any custom function?**

Comment: use `knit(input, output, envir = .GlobalEnv)` or something inside of `k`

Comment: That does fix the issue, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use the global environment. My motivation for putting the `knit` call in a function was that so the objects didn't sit around and could be garbage collected.

Comment: Instead of `globalenv()`, you should probably use `parent.frame()`.

Comment: @rawr and Yihui, thanks for your help. I've managed to isolate it as a data.table issue. Could one of you post an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: My issue is basically https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1369

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to pass through the function explicitly as I found out from [this comment](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1369#issuecomment-145077464) on the data.table issue page:

```
f <- function(d, fun.aggregate){
  dcast(d,  drat ~ cyl, fun.aggregate = fun.aggregate, value.var = "carb") 
}
```